UV unwrapping and texturing large objects
I am trying to texture this wooden cladding of a large house model. I have UV unwrapped my object, which results in very low resolution textures, due to the size of the model. When I try to texture paint some grunge, the resolution is also very low, as you can see in the image. What solution can I use to keep my UV maps from overlapping, but also keeping the scale of the maps sufficient enough to have a high resolution texture?

I have just scaled my PBR texture using nodes to match the scale of the building, but this doesn't seem like a viable or clean solution, since I am having issues with other things like texture painting. Therefore, I think I need a way to UV unwrap more efficiently but I don't see how that's possible yet for such large objects.

Would appreciate any tips on uv unwrapping / texturing for what I'm trying to do, Thanks.

First of all, the UV canvas can be scale  to match any resolution, but obviously the bigger, the more hardware resources you will use (2K, 4K, 8K). Second of all, you don't have to put your whole object in one single texture, you could split it and have a texture per part or create UDIM textures

Environment art is always going to use Trimsheets/Tiling textures and masks or vertex paint blending to texture objects. You almost never use unique 0-1 UVs like you would for a prop or character.

yeah, I'm gonna use a larger colour range for blending my textures together. I just wanted to know how I can work around this resolution issue. I will look into UDIM textures and look into using trimsheets for future projects to make things easier. thanks for the tips.
